# How can I remove the unique option from a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a field in my db called "user" which is unique.

I would like to remove the "unique" option so I can have couple of users with the same nickname.

Which sql statement should I execute to perform this action ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
DROP INDEX name_of_your_unique_index;
```

UNIQUE is an index, so just drop it.